# Detect moving between cells using keyboard

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-3.5

In `PyQt` `QTableWidget`, **how to detect moving between cells using keyboard?**
It is detect moving between cells using mouse click but using keyboard, it doesn't detect. 
I can not detect moving between cells using the keyboard

Version: 
`pyqt` 4.11.4 
 `python` 3.5.3

```
def func_mappingSignal(self):
    self.table_profile.cellClicked.connect(self.func_cellClickedTableModelProfile)
    self.table_profile.cellActivated.connect(self.func_cellActivated)
    self.table_profile.cellEntered.connect(self.func_cellEntered)
    self.table_profile.itemActivated.connect(self.func_itemActivated)
```

I used these methods. But not all methods detect it.

Comment: What do you mean `moving between cells`?

Comment: @eyllanesc It means move (1, 0) cell to (1,1) cell.

Comment: You could place the code as you enable to move the cells to take it as a reference.

Comment: @eyllanesc For example...?

Comment: You make me an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @eyllanesc Oops, sorry. I did not mean to offend.

Comment: I do not understand you, you have not offended me, what I ask is an example where you can test and take it as a basis to help you.